# hapi.js - 404 route VS static files route

Tags: node.js, redirect, http-status-code-404, hapi.js

I'm trying to migrate my Express app to hapi.js, and I having trouble with my routes. I just want 2 GET : my index '/', and everything that is not '/' to redirect to '/'.

Using Express I had this:

```
// static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// index route
app.get('/', function (req, res) { 
  // whatever
}

// everything that is not /
app.get('*', function(req, res) { 
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

I have issues with hapi.js to get the same behaviour. My "static road" looks like this:

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/{path*}',
  handler: {
    directory: {
      path: 'public',
      listing: false
    }
  }
});
```

and my "404 road" would be:

```
server.route({ 
  method: 'GET', 
  path: '/{path*}', 
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    reply.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

and I get this error:

```
Error: New route /{path*} conflicts with existing /{path*}
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 14):

You're defining 2 routes with the same method and path, which is a conflict as far as hapi's router is concerned. That's why you're getting the error.

If a file isn't found by the `directory` handler, it will respond with a 404 error by default.

What you can do is intercept this with an `onPreReponse` handler, which checks if the response is an error response (a [Boom](https://github.com/hapijs/boom) object), and if so respond however you wish. In your case by redirecting to `/`:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 4000 });

server.route([{
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            reply('Welcome home!');
        }
    }, {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{p*}',
        handler: {
            directory: {
                path: 'public',
                listing: false
            }
        }
    }
]);

server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, reply) {

    if (request.response.isBoom) {
        // Inspect the response here, perhaps see if it's a 404?
        return reply.redirect('/');
    }

    return reply.continue();
});

    
server.start(function () {
    console.log('Started server');
});
```

Recommended reading:

- hapi's request lifecycle and extension points: http://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle
- The response object: http://hapijs.com/api#response-object

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like your approach to deal with status code. However, to gain time, I chose to change my static path to delete conflits with 404.

Comment: @ThibaudTallon, I think that's definitely a wise idea, if your application allows it. Although extension points are powerful, it's a good idea to minimise their usage I think.