# hapi catch all route without assets folder 404 status

Tags: hapi.js

I'm working on a SPA
and I want to manage the 404 status
but without using a separate folder
(assets in this case)

```
server.route(
    {    // Angular/API Route
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
             reply( {api: 'response' } )
        }
    });

    server.route({    // Other assets If you have
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/assets/{param*}',
        handler: {
        directory: {
            path: './assets',
            listing: false,
            index: true
        }
    });

    server.route({   // Everything else 
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{p*}',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            reply.file('public/html/index.html');
        }
    });
```

I mean I've got a deploy like

[image: deploy]

so if I use assets I've to change all my deploy
and gulpfile.

Is there a way to manage 404 status without using
an extra folder ?

**UPDATE**
by now I worked it out following the tip of @Matt Harrison

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, reply) {
    var req = request.response;
    if (req.isBoom && (req.output.statusCode===404)) {
      return reply.redirect('/#!/404');
    }
    return reply.continue();
});
```

Comment: Similar question/answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305065/hapi-js-404-route-vs-static-files-route/29310691#29310691

Comment: yeah similar but not the same I'm asking for a way to not use assets folder

Comment: this is more relate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396060/nodejs-hapi-single-page but don't work out my problem

Comment: the answer I posted answers your question too. Just change `reply.redirect('/');` to `reply.file('public/html/index.html');`

Comment: ok I can see the point thanks